# How to know new value of primary key in UPDATE trigger? (T-SQL)

Tags: t-sql, triggers, primary-key

I have a table:

CREATE TABLE Demo (
    id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY
);

I want to create an AFTER UPDATE (or INSTEAD OF UPDATE) trigger, and I need to know OLD and NEW values of "id" column inside the trigger.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This isn't possible.

If the table has 2 rows and you update both of them there is no way of knowing which row in `INSERTED` maps to which in `DELETED`.

You can use the `OUTPUT` clause for this (outside a trigger) though.

Or you could add an `IDENTITY` column to the table and use that to join `INSERTED` and `DELETED` (it is not permitted to update identity columns so that gives you something immutable)